# Software to enable and disable a Keyboard on Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, keyboard

I'm looking for software that gives me the ability to enable and disable my keyboard. The reason for this is that when I study, I like to have my textbook right on top of my laptop's keyboard; however, by doing so it may accidently press random keys. I would like the software to meet the following requirements,

- Gratis
- Compatible with Windows 10 64bit
- Does not also disable (or, at least, gives the option to disable) my mouse
- Ability to enable and disable the keyboard through the use of a mouse, not the actual keyboard

Some features that are not requirements but wanted are,

- Ability to turn on/off a list of keyboards that are connected to my computer (Software would list out the connected keyboards and I could turn each one on or off)

Comment: In the **Device Manager** you can disable any device.

Comment: @cybernard I'm looking for software specifically designed for this task, using the device manager isn't really what I'm looking for

Answer (score 4):

The free [Keyboard Locker](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11570/disable-the-keyboard-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-windows/) will cover you on the part of locking your Keyboard !

From http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11570/disable-the-keyboard-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-windows/

> Keyboard Locker is a small program that does this job well and takes up very few system resources. It’s a small AutoHotKey script.

Optionally, you can read the guide for creating a shortcut or adding it to Windows Startup in case you want to have it loaded by default.

Download it through the link at the end of the presentation article.

**Instructions**

> 1. Download the file and extract the Keyboard Locker anywhere you like
> 2. Open KeyboardLocker.exe
> 3. Press Ctrl+Alt+L to lock your keyboard
> 4. Type "unlock" without the quotes to unlock your keyboard

You can also make your own modifications by editing the **KeyboardLocker.ahk** file, like enabling your mouse buttons to unlock your keyboard. Learn about the Script Syntax on [AutoHotkey Docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm).

**Note:** It does not support Windows XP, OS X & Linux. It does not require to have [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) installed.

Comment: Updated with more details